# Deploying Google Cloud Function by Terraform got "Error 400: The request has errors, badRequest"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to deploy Cloud Function by Terraform but it fails.

`export TF_LOG=DEBUG`
`terraform init`
`terraform plan # it does not fail`
`terraform apply # this fail`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The request has errors",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request has errors",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

## What I tired

- I tried to change the trigger to HTTP but the deployment also failed.
- enable TF_LOG
- do `terraform plan` but it succeeded

## terraform template

below is my main.tf file

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "topic" {
  name    = "rss-webhook-topic"
  project = "${var.project_id}"
}


resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  name                = "rss-webhook-function"
  entry_point         = "helloGET"
  available_memory_mb = 256
  project             = "${var.project_id}"

  event_trigger {
    event_type = "google.pubsub.topic.publish"
    resource   = "${google_pubsub_topic.topic.name}"
  }

  source_archive_bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
  source_archive_object = "${google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name}"
}

data "archive_file" "function_src" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "function_src.zip"

  source {
    content  = "${file("src/index.js")}"
    filename = "index.js"
  }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "archive" {
  name       = "function_src.zip"
  bucket     = "${var.bucket_name}"
  source     = "function_src.zip"
  depends_on = ["data.archive_file.function_src"]
}
```

## environment

Terraform version: 0.11.13
Go runtime version: go1.12
+ provider.archive v1.2.2
+ provider.google v2.5.1

Comment: Where is this defined `google_pubsub_topic.topic.name`?

Comment: I edit my post. Original template has topic which can be deployed.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying with "Original template has topic which can be deployed." Are you saying it is now working?

Comment: At first I added topic to template and deploy. it worked. After that I add Cloud Functions to template and the deployment fails.

Answer (score 1):

property "runtime" is required.

below works.

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  name                = "rss-webhook-function"
  entry_point         = "helloGET"
  available_memory_mb = 256
  project             = "${var.project_id}"
  runtime             = "nodejs8"

  event_trigger {
    event_type = "google.pubsub.topic.publish"
    resource   = "${google_pubsub_topic.topic.name}"
  }

  source_archive_bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
  source_archive_object = "${google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name}"
}
```